# Is it possible top have nested dropdown in image_list in insert/edit image plugin in Tinymce 5?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

In our old version of tinymce we used to have nested dropdown in image_list in insert/edit image plugin, see the attached image. But recently we migrated to tinymce 5.4.2 and since then it's not working.

Old code:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  
  plugins: 'image',
  menubar: 'insert',
  toolbar: 'image',
  image_list:  [
                    {
                        title: "LearnCenter", menu: [{ title: 'Logo', value: 'Logo' }]
                    },
                    {
                        title: "UserAccount", menu: [{ title: 'Photo', value: 'Photo' }]
                    }
               ]
});
```

Above code is not working anymore so we made changes, see below code:

```
image_list: [{ title: 'Logo', value: 'Logo' },
               { title: 'Photo', value: 'Photo' }]
```

But after this code change, nest dropdown is gone. Is there any way by which we can have same functionality that we used to have. See the attached image for expected functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature, using TinyMCE 4.x JSON structure, is set to return in TinyMCE 5.5, which, as of the time of posting this, is scheduled to be available later this month.

Comment: Thank you so much. Once it's out I know what changes I need to make.